# Trouble batch setting a document field by docId in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using firebase (firestore) for a while but I'm a little stuck and was wondering if anyone can think of a solution.

On the firestore DB I have a single collection of users, each user has an email address and several other fields. In this instance I am checking if a user email exists and if it does, I want to create a list field for that particular user with a listUid. I am referencing the users by email, grabbing the docId for those users and then trying to set a list field for each of them.

I am not getting any error's from firestore, it's simply not updating in the DB for some reason and I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

```
export const addListUidToExistingUserList = (
  { firestore },
  emailArray,
  listUid
) => {
  return async () => {
    let docIds = [];

    emailArray.forEach((emailAddress) => {
      //find users by email (works)
      const query = db
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", "==", emailAddress);

      //get docId's for user with matching email (works)
      query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          docIds.push(doc.id);
        });
      });

      //add a new list with corresponding listUid (does not work)
      docIds.forEach((id) => {
        let userRef = db.collection("users").doc(id);
        batch.set(userRef, { lists: [{ listUid }] });
      });
    });
    return await batch.commit();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into this issue because your `docIds` array is always empty at the time you call `docIds.forEach`.

That's because `query.get().then` runs asynchronously, and so `docIds.forEach` is not waiting for it to complete.

You could either:

- `await query.get().then`; or
- Add the `docIds.forEach` function INSIDE the `then` callback of `query.get`.

Here are your possible fixes:

1. `await query.get().then`

```
//get docId's for user with matching email (works)
await query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    docIds.push(doc.id);
  });
});
```

OR:

2. `docIds.forEach` inside `then`

```
//get docId's for user with matching email (works)
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    docIds.push(doc.id);
  });

  docIds.forEach((id) => {
    let userRef = db.collection("users").doc(id);
    batch.set(userRef, { lists: [{ listUid }] });
  });
});
```

> Note: Of course, you could also add `batch.set` directly into your first iteration of `querySnapshot.docs.forEach` to prevent an unnecessary iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, makes sense but now I'm getting `A write batch can no longer be used after commit() has been called.` Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: I have actually solved the `batch.commit()` issue. I was calling db.batch() outside the function's scope. So, the first time that function runs, it calls batch.commit() and it commits all changes. So, when that function runs again, we get that error because commit was already called for that instance. The solution was to call inside scope !